# How can I add values from checkboxes to a URL string as grouped parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw lots of similar question where you can extract the values of Checkboxes based on the check uncheck and add them to URL, but if we have different categories of checkbox  group, separate them with &.
Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var swapRelation = "";
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e) {
            var seasoning = "",
                parentRelation = "",
                tempArray = [];
            
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
                tempArray.push($(this).attr("name").replace(/\s/g, ''));
                parentRelation = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find('.catName').text().trim();
                parentRelation = parentRelation.replace(/\s/g, '');

            });
            if (tempArray.length !== 0) {
                seasoning += `${parentRelation}=` + tempArray.toString();
                // if (swapRelation == parentRelation) {
                //     // seasoning+=`&${parentRelation}=`+tempArray.toString();
                //     seasoning += `${parentRelation}=` + tempArray.toString();
                // }else {
                    
                // }
                
                //tempArray = [];
                swapRelation = parentRelation;
            }
            console.log("example.com?" + seasoning);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="catName">Fruits</div>
    <div class="checkBoxWrap">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="apple" id="input-5">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="banana" id="input-6">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="mango" id="input-7">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="catName">Vaegs</div>
    <div class="checkBoxWrap">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="Okra" id="input-8">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="Patato" id="input-9">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="Tamato" id="input-10">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="catName">Rivers</div>
    <div class="checkBoxWrap">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="Ganga" id="input-11">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="yamuna" id="input-12">
        <input class="input__field" type="checkbox" name="thames" id="input-13">
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected Result on multiple Selections:

**URL?Fruits=banana,mango&Vegs=okra,patato&Rivers=ganga,whateverSelected**

Comment: You probably want an `each` function for each category, so it builds its own array.

Comment: Why not give the checkbox groups the same name: `name="fruits[]"`, with different values: `value="apple"`, `value="banana"`, `value="mango"`, and let the URL construction happen naturally, like `?fruits[]=apple&fruits[]=banana&fruits[]=mango`. Is there a reason you need it as a CSV in the URL?

Comment: How about [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with `,` as the separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to build your query string.

```
var usp = new URLSearchParams();
document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper').forEach((wrapperDiv)=> {
    var category = wrapperDiv.querySelector('.catName').textContent;
    var checkedBoxes = wrapperDiv.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var values = Array.from(checkedBoxes, cb=>cb.name).join('');
    usp.append(category,values);
});
```